# Limit parameter on google API response

Tags: api, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-tasks-api

I am looking for limit parameter by which I can limit the the data that I am get. Like I want to get the list of tasks. By which I can get the list of task.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/{{tasklist_id}}/tasks?maxResults=50&order=date
```

But here I got the recently 50 tasks, but when I call this url I must get the data after last data received. 
So if there any since parameter by which I can limit the response and my data would not loss please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit parameter.  there is only max results and max results is more like per page.

If a request will return 100 rows, and you place maxresults 50 then the first response you will get back will contain 50 rows.  You will have to make a second request to get the next 50.

Google [tasks.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/list) returns a response

```
{
  "kind": "tasks#tasks",
  "etag": string,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "items": [
    tasks Resource
  ]
}
```

This is a response for the request made at this exact time.   If you had sent maxresults 50 and 100 rows would be returned then you use NextPageToken to get the next 50 rows for this request.

If after you run that request new records arrive into the system those records will not come in the previous request because that is the data built at the time the request was sent.

**Example:**

I make a request against the API.  I set max rows to 1

```
1, test
2, test2 
3, test3
```

the API will return to me `1, test` with a nextPageToken I can use to get the next set of results.  I make a request using the NextPageToken I get 2, test2

If while I am looping though these `NextPagetokens` a new row arrives `4, test4` I will not see this because it wasn't part of the result set of my initial query.

Comment: Ok fine. If suppose 100 rows created I got 50 rows in a 1st call. after 1st call another 50 more row created, so it will return me the latest 50 rows in another call, So here I lost my remaining 50 rows data. SO here I lost my imp data.

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/{{tasklist_id}}/tasks?maxResults=50&order=date <-- that is one request   it returns 100 rows (NOW)  if new data arrived in that time then its a different request and you will have to make another request to get the newer data after the initial request was made.

Comment: You did not get me . I'm saying that. If I make this request googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists{{tasklist_id}}/tasks?maxResults=5&or‌​der=date
and at the time of request another 10 task created, so I will return the latest 5 task. and if again I made request then no new task I'll get. So I lost here my 5 task data

Comment: then you will get 5 rows back the first request then you use nextpagetoken to get the next 5 rows, ....

Comment: what is nextpagetoken? How can I use it?

Comment: The total number of rows returned by a single request is the number of rows that are there at the time you make the request.   it doesn't matter if there comes more rows there will still only be 100 rows.

Comment: nextPageToken string Token used to access the next page of this result.

Comment: can you give me an example of using next page token in my request?

Comment: check the documentation there are examples in java, php, python and .net https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/list  Nextpagetoken is normally just a url yo should just be able to execute it using the accesstoken

Comment: Why I am not getting NextpageToken In my response?

Comment: because there aren't anymore rows.

Answer (score 0):

[Tasks: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/list) supports a `updatedMin` parameter with a RFC 3339 timestamp which will restrict the returned tasks to those that were updated since that time.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/{{tasklist_id}}/tasks?maxResults=50&order=date&updatedMin=2015-09-17T15:52:20Z
```